# How can display value after ModelState.IsValid return false

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I work on simple MVC app. In my `EditProduct` view I want to display current category for product in disable input. I have and a drop down list where user can choose category with option label "Select Category".

View `EditProduct`:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="disabledInput" class="control-label col-md-2"><b>Current Category</b></label> 
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input class="form-control" id="disabledInput" type="text" placeholder="@Model.Category" disabled>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryID, "Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("CategoryID", (SelectList)ViewBag.CategoryID, "Select Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control " })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID, "", new { @class = "text-success" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

I put in placeholder of input value `@Model.Category`. This is the name of current product.

User is required to choose category:

```
public class ProductsViewModel
{
    \\ .....

    public string Category { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Category is required.")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
}
```

When I select product to edit, everything is OK - the current category is display in a input. If I select category and click save also is OK.

But, if I dont choose category and click save, `ModelState.IsValid` return false and then `@Model.Category` is gone from a input.

How can display product current category after ModelState.IsValid return false with this approach? Or another way to do that?

Comment: A few potential issues with your code. First a disabled input does not post back anything so it will always be null when you return the view (make it readonly instead). And you should never name the `SelectList` the same name as the property your binding to (change it to say `ViewBag.CategoryList`)

Comment: Also your disabled input does not have either a `name` or `value` attribute so it wont post back anything even if you make it readonly. Create a new property say CurrentCategory and bind to it.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I change name of my viewbag to `ViewBag.CategoryList` and this bind my current product category to drop down list. I want just that. I delete input and everithing is now OK. Thanks for help!

Comment: I'll post an answer to explain some of the other issues you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manually creating a input that does not have a `name` attribute or a `value` attribute and is `disabled`. All 3 mean nothing relating to that input will post back so when you return the view, `Category` is `null`. The next problem is your dropdown list is also binding to a property named `CategoryID` and your `SelectList` also has the same name which will cause problems. Then you have a class which indicates its a view model but continue to use `ViewBag` (why?).

Change the view model to

```
public class ProductsViewModel
{
    .....

    public string Category { get; set; } // see notes below

    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Category is required.")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public SelectList CategoryList { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the view

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryID, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryID, Model.CategoryList, "Select Category", new { @class = "form-control " })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryID, new { @class = "text-success" })
```

And in the controller

```
public ActionResult Edit(int ID)
{
  ProductsViewModel model = new ProductsViewModel();
  model.CategoryList = new SelectList(db.Categories, "ID", "Name"); // adjust parameters to suit
  model.CategoryID = ?; // set this if you want an initial option displayed
  return View(model);
}
```

Now when the page is initially rendered, the selected option will be displayed based on the value of `CategoryID`. Its not clear why you would also want to display the same value in a textbox as well, but if so, the assign the category name to property `string Category` and use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Category, new { readonly = "readonly" })
```

which will create a 'read-only' textbox containing the initial value of `Category` and will post back.

Comment: Your explain is very helpfull for me. I corrected my code and now is clear and works perfect. This is my very first project and I know to learn many things, but you help me a lot for concept of view models. Sorry for my english, thanks!